Strict equality check doesn't work as intended
I'm working on a problem on CodeWars and everything is working fine except for one detail, the vectors (1,2 1,-2) should equal to false but the code that I've made says otherwise. -2 % 1 equates to -0 but it still shows up as true. This is my first time using this platform and I apologize if the solution to this problem is very simple.


function collinearity(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  switch (true) {
    case y1 % x1 === 0 && y2 % x2 === 0:
      return true;
    case x1 + x2 === 0 || (y1 === 0 && y2 === 0):
      return true;
    case x1 + y1 === 0 || x2 + y2 === 0:
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

console.log(collinearity(1, 2, 1, -2));




Even if you use Object.is, 2 % -1 is positive zero, so relying on this particular number quirk doesn’t work for this application.

-0 === 0 is true. They represent the same value the -0 is just a quirk of the floating point standard
